# How to know if the entered letter is a vowel or a consonant

Tags: qbasic

```
CLS
INPUT "enter any letter"; a$
b$ = UCASE$(a$)
SELECT CASE b$
    CASE "a", "e", "i", "o", "u"
END SELECT
IF c$ = b$ THEN
    PRINT "Vowel"
ELSE
    PRINT "consonant"
END IF
END
```

Comment: What language are you using? Also, how did your code go wrong? what it it output?

Comment: @QuinnFreedman QBasic was a programming language of Microsoft (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic) which got a syntax similar to Pascal and is very old. Nowadays I wouldn't recommend coding with it.

Comment: Here is an online emulator with Nibbles ak. Snake running by default: http://stevehanov.ca/blog/?id=92

Comment: Where is a value set into c$? Also ... Why do you test with lowercase vowels when you set b$ with uppercase chars!? What do you think happens if a$ is a word!?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to compare with lowercase letters, be sure to use LCASE$ instead of UCASE$

```
CLS
INPUT "enter any letter"; a$
b$ = LCASE$(a$)
SELECT CASE b$
  CASE "a", "e", "i", "o", "u"
    PRINT "Vowel"
  CASE ELSE
    PRINT "consonant"
END SELECT
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `INSTR` function to find out if the inputted character is in the list of vowels:

```
CLS
INPUT "enter any letter"; a$
IF INSTR("AEIOUaeiou", a$) THEN
    PRINT "Vowel"
ELSE
    PRINT "Consonant"
END IF
END
```

Not better but feasible is using `UCASE$':

```
CLS
INPUT "enter any letter"; a$
a$ = UCASE$(a$)
IF INSTR("AEIOU", a$) THEN
    PRINT "Vowel"
ELSE
    PRINT "Consonant"
END IF
END
```